# Bind string from .resx ResourceDictionary to TextBlock.Text using index key

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, localization, resx

i'm trying to get my view in different languages, using Properties/Resources.resx file for localization.

I've my model looks like the following:

```
class City 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string LocalizationKey { get; set; }
}
```

The ViewModel:

```
class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<City> Cities { get; set; }
}
```

And on my View, i've the following code:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Cities}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding LocalizationKey}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

When i want to get the value of my string key from the dictionary for only one item without Items Collection it works correctly by using the following code:

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Static properties:Resources.MyStringKey}" />
```

The problem is when using the code above with an ItemsControl where the keys are unknowns! Is there any way to access to the dictionary values by using the LocalizationKey as an index?

Comment: Please see the [WPF Globalization and Localization Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788718(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN for information on Localization in WPF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of web searching, i finally found a solution by using a converter, it may not the best practices to solve the problem but at least it does exactly what i want:

My Converter:

```
public class LocalizationConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var key = value as string;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
        {
            string dictionaryValue = Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(key);
            return dictionaryValue ?? key;
        }
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and the XAML code:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding LocalizationId, Converter={StaticResource LocalizationConverter}}" />
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Can you do something like:

```
public class City
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string LocalizationKey { get; set; }
    public City(string englishName)
    {
        LocalizationKey = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(englishName);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure this best practice; but it what came to mind first.

Comment: It may works, but in the model there is no constructor with the CityName parameter, in fact, it's just an example to simulate the problem, all values are stored on a Resources resx files (Resources.resx, Resources.fr-FR.resx... )

Comment: @cYounes so do you set the Id at some point, and you want to use Id to retrieve the string from Resources and set LocalizationKey?

Comment: no, the Id is not used for localization in my case, it's just another property in my Model.

Comment: @cYounes Okay, there must be a miscommunication. I'm not sure how you generate your Cities collection. In short, you need to use some variation of `ResourceManager`.  My thought is put your City names in a new Properties/Cities.resx file, then create a ResourceManager using that file, and [enumerate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg418542(v=vs.110).aspx) all the keys and set each `City`'s `LocalizationKey`. Can you apply that method?