# How can I localize DisplayMemberBinding in GridViewColumn to a resx file?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I use GUI text localization with resx files in my app:

For example I write like this to fetch the GUI text into a TextBlock:

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Static GuiText.LoginView.LoginText}" FontSize="24"\>
```

But how can I fetch localized text into a GridViewColumn?

How could I localize the following?

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Value" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Value}" />
```

The Header I can localize at least like this:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="{x:Static GuiText.LoginView.HeaderValueText}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Value}" />
```

But how do I localize the translation of the **DisplayMemberBinding**?

Comment: You mean , you have culture-specific values? What type are those? If string and the value is a key into some resx: You could use a ValueConverter, maybe. But it remains a little unclear to me.

Comment: Yes, I want the value to be a key into the resx file. The resx file has two string columns . First column is where I want to lookup the value and then from column two I want to get a string to raplace that value with.

Comment: Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23949941/982149

Comment: But can't this be handled with only XAML? Must I write a Converter?

Comment: What exactly do you want to localize? "Value" refers to the name of a property and these aren't localized...

Answer (score 1):

> But how do I localize the translation of the `DisplayMemberBinding`?

The binding path of a `DisplayMemberBinding` refers to a property name and these aren't localized.

The property that you bind to should return an already translated value, e.g.:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="{x:Static GuiText.LoginView.HeaderValueText}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=TranslatedValue}" />
```

---

```
public string TranslatedValue
{
    get
    {
        return Resource1.String1;
    }
}
```